# Populating table with object containing an array in vuejs?

Tags: html-table, vue.js

I am trying to populate table with an object which contains an array. I am able to successfully do that but I want each task name to have its own row right now they are coming in a single row.

```
{level_image :"image"level_name:"1"task_name: ["game","taskgame","jenga"]}
```

```
<tr v-for="tel in result" :key="tel.level_image" :pey="tel.level_name">
                  <td>{{tel.level_image}}</td>
                  <td>{{tel.level_name}}</td>
                  <td  v-for="task in tel.task_name">{{task}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the obvious: if you want each one to have its own row, you need to put the `v-for` in a `<tr>` tag (like you did for `result`). Exactly how you deal with the `<td>`s is up in the air, but it might go like this:

```
<tr v-for="tel in result" :key="tel.level_image" :pey="tel.level_name">
  <tr v-for="task in tel.task_name">
    <td>{{tel.level_image}}</td>
    <td>{{tel.level_name}}</td>
    <td>{{task}}</td>
  </tr>
</tr>
```

Or if you mean you want each one to be on a separate line within a table cell, it could be

```
<tr v-for="tel in result" :key="tel.level_image" :pey="tel.level_name">
  <td>{{tel.level_image}}</td>
  <td>{{tel.level_name}}</td>
  <td><div v-for="task in tel.task_name">{{task}}</div></td>
</tr>
```

The main idea is that you want the `v-for` to be associated with the type of tag that creates the entity you want each `task` in.

Comment: I'd like to leave my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/3dezpte0/) to have a working example here.